# XML schema - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a new question about the same code. Now all my words (only one in the original example, but I have more in my file) in the XML-file have id:s, like this:

```
<words id="wordone">clock</words> 
<words id="wordtwo">sleep</words>
```

And now I have to change the code in my XML-schema too, but I can't figure out how. I have this now:

```
<xsd:element name="words" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

And I thought that would work, because the name of the words are still "words", but I get an error. What do I miss?

---

Im new at this and I need some help. :) This is my first try and my XML schema looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- File Name: words.xsd -->

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>
        Lexicon spanish english
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="english">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="listwords"/>
            <xsd:element name="language" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="authur" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="allwords" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="words" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>  
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and my XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="main.css"?>
<english xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="words.xsd">
<!-- Filename: english.xml -->
<!-- Authur: FL -->
<!-- Date: 2016-11-15 -->

<listwords>
    <language>English</language>
    <authur>FL</authur>
    <allwords>
        <words>clock</words>    
    </allwords>
</listwords>
```

The error: "XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

Help? :)

Comment: As the first two answerers have indicated, your immediate error is due to a missing end tag for `english`.  However, you have other structural problems with the agreement between your XSD and XML files.  Which one do you wish to change to match the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `</english>` at the bottom of your file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="main.css"?>
<english xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="words.xsd">
<!-- Filename: english.xml -->
<!-- Authur: FL -->
<!-- Date: 2016-11-15 -->

<listwords>
    <language>English</language>
    <authur>FL</authur>
    <allwords>
        <words>clock</words>    
    </allwords>
</listwords>
</english>
```